# How to make menu using dict evaluation for small python guessing game

Tags: python, function, dictionary, menu, eval

```
menu = {
"1": "start_game()"
"2": "player_stats()"
"3": "high_scores()"
"0": "exit_game()"
}
```

So let's say if user inputs 1 in menu screen, I want to call **start_game()** function, I know there is other way to do this but just interested in this particular way because I think its neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put strings in the dictionary, put references to the function.

```
menu = {
    "1": start_game,
    "2": player_stats,
    "3": high_scores,
    "0": exit_game
}
```

Then you can do:

```
choice = input("Please enter 1, 2, 3, or 0: ")
menu[choice]()
```

to execute the user's choice.